# Excluding posts that are in a certain category

Tags: vue.js, graphql

New to graphQL here to bear with me. I've read the docs and googled as best as I can but all I got were simplified answers and they didn't help.

I'm using WordPress as my data source.

I've been able to show posts that are in a specific category but I'm struggling to show all posts EXCEPT those in a certain category.

I want to get all posts EXCLUDING ones that are in the "Portfolio" category (ID: 10)

The top line "works" but it's only looking at the id of the post itself, not the categories it is in. The second line me what my brain thinks it should be but it doesn't work.

Please help if you can :)

```
query Home($page: Int) {
  allWordPressPost(page: $page, perPage: 10, filter: { id: { nin: [12] }}) @paginate {
# allWordPressPost(page: $page, perPage: 10, filter: { categories.id: { nin: [12] }}) @paginate {
    pageInfo {
      totalPages
      currentPage
    }
    edges {
      node {
        id
        title
        path
        excerpt

        categories {
          id
          title
          path
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This question looks like it relates to gridsome and @gridsome/source-wordpress specifically. If that's the case, it would be good to edit it to mention that fact and add the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look to this [repo](https://github.com/pehaa/gridsome-starter-wordpress-bootstrap)?

I don't know if it helps, but this starter is probably better rather than the official one for this purpose!